# Ik go wrong in render animation, but fine in viewport and render image

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

After I set my keys, I render the scene (shift+f12 Render animation), the result has a weird shaking and displacement on IK. But it was okay if I render every single frame by myself (f12 x 40time).

[Render animation mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUsm295EZeR-HWKavci2TV6HgiJE6oXH/view?usp=sharing)

[Render by me, every single frame. mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BUZPEmdkjruQ-PmyrMTeI8_ny6r_ZA49/view?usp=sharing)

It feel like blender forgot update ik location or render before ik moveing to the right spot.

Is there a way to solve this problem so that I could render automatically when I go to sleep?

[Here is my blender file, I am using 2.90.1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kFSEHhVb5z7_G9PNIGZ6A9-uKawB_t43/view?usp=sharing)

Sorry for my poor English and thank you for the reading.

Comment: I tried it again. A weird shaking was rendered in v.2.90.1, but not in v.2.91.0.

Comment: wow it work, it look fine in 2.91, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it's turned out to be a bug. I don't have IKs but I remapped the keyframes from 30fps to 24fps so CTRL+F12 renders the armature animation incorrect. I needed toon shading of the octane renderer so I couldn't upgrade the Blender but instead rendered the blend file one frame at a time in cmd with a for loop

for /l %x in (118, 1, 375) do blender -b octane.blend -f %x

118, start frame.
1, step.
375, end frame.